# Fabry-Perot cavity modelling

Tags: optics, interferometry

I'm trying to understand the modelling used for Fabry-Perot cavities, such as it is done in e.g. this paper: http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1729109

The model given is based on the following diagram:

[image: Fabry-Perot cavity]

The boundary conditions are given as ($r$ and $t$ are the reflection and transmission coefficients, respectively)
$$R_2 = t R_1^*$$
$$L_1^* = -r R_1^*$$
$$R_1 = -r L_1 + t R_0$$
$$L_0 = t L_1 + r R_0$$
and the resulting expression for the intensity of the reflected intensity $|L_0|^2/|R_0|^2$ seem to correspond well to measurements from an experimental set-up we have using a HeNe laser source.

[image: Model]
[image: Measurements]

However, one might expect the last boundary condition to be
$$L_0 = t L_1 - r R_0$$
to be consistent with the first three boundary conditions but this gives a different expression for the reflected intensity.

Are the signs chosen in the paper in the expression for $L_0$ correct, and if they are, why?

Comment: Are any justifications or explanations given for the boundary conditions?

Comment: Or, rather, why would the sign of the second term need to change in order to be consistent?

Comment: @BillyKalfus The justifications given are sparse, so I assume the authors assume the readers might know this somehow. I would expect the signs to correspond to the directions of the fields (hence why I think there should be a -r and not a +r in the L_0 expression)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper is correct. The sign of the reflection coefficient depends on which side of the boundary has a higher index of refraction. It seems the paper assumes the index is smaller inside the slab region, so that light reflected back into the slab region carries extra minus sign. For light reflecting back into the ouside (higher index), there is no minus sign.

EDIT: @Samuel Weir (in the comment below) is right. I added an illustration to describe the situation more accurately.

[image]

Comment: To clarify further, there is a 180˚ phase shift when light reflects off an interface in which the index of refraction increases (e.g., air-to-glass), but no phase shift when light reflects off an interface in which the index of refraction decreases (e.g., glass-to-air). The 2nd and 3rd equations involve reflections off air-to-glass interfaces, so negative signs are needed in their terms to account for the 180˚ phase shifts. The 4th equation involves a reflection off a glass-to-air interface.